# Firebase Test Lab rerun test with same uploaded APK

Tags: android, firebase-test-lab

I working on developing Android Instrumentation Tests written in Espresso.  As part of the effort, I am uploading and running in Firebase Test Lab using the Firebase Console.  It would save me a lot of time if I didn't have to upload the App APK every time I want to re-run a test.
Does anybody know if Firebase Test Lab stores uploaded App and Test APKs so that a test can be re-run without requiring APKs to be uploaded again? Or an option in the Firebase Test Lab console to access an App APK that was previously uploaded?

I tried to use Firebase Storage but I can't access the files from Test Lab.

Maybe using Cloud SDK command line interface it best option since the test run will be automatically initiated once the APKs load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files (and APKs) that you pass to `gcloud firebase test android run` can be both from the local file system, as well as files stored in Google Cloud Storage. E.g. see the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run#--app) for the `--app` argument.

If you don't want to pass these files for every test invocation, upload them first to GCS with `gsutil`:

```sh
gsutil cp myapp.apk gs://my-bucket/myapp.apk
```

Then, use them for every test run:

```sh
gcloud firebase test android run --app gs://my-bucket/myapp.apk
```

Comment: Thanks!  Works great